# SSL Handshake fails after JDK Upgrade from 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: security, ssl

I have enabled One Way SSL on one of the managed server in cluster in weblogic10.3.6 server. Earlier the JAVA version used was 1.6. But later it has been upgraded to 1.8.  I am running a standalone jar that hit the above mentioned managed server on t3s protocol to make some initial context for some EJB lookup, using below command.

```
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <Se`enter code here`curitySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:23 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:24 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Got SSLContext, protocol=TLS, provider=SunJSSE>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(String[]): value=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols(String[]): value=SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(boolean): value=true.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setWantClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 208.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]).
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:664)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:505)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:448)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:80)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:64)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:59)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:390)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:78)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.connect(MuxableSocketT3.java:404)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.ConnectionFactoryT3S.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryT3S.java:44)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1792)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.findOrCreateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1424)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:443)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:321)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:260)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:141)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:128)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:84)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:41)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1000)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.main(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:131)
>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.closeOutbound(): value=closed.>
<Oct 18, 2015 4:41:25 PM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[main,5,main]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 7.>
[2015/10/18 16:41:25][ERROR][TriggerSynchronizationProcess]:Error while fetching common configuration. Error isUnable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.CommonConfigurationException: Unable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:143)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:128)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:84)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:41)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1000)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.main(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:131)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination]
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:792)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:368)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:141)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:470)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:321)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:260)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
        ... 16 more
[2015/10/18 16:41:25][ERROR][TriggerSynchronizationProcess]:Exception occured. Error is Error while fetching common configuration. Error isUnable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
java.lang.Exception: Error while fetching common configuration. Error isUnable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1081)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.main(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:131)
Caused by: com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.CommonConfigurationException: Unable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:143)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:128)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:84)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:41)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1000)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination]
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:792)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:368)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:141)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:470)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:321)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:260)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
        ... 16 more
java.lang.Exception: Error while fetching common configuration. Error isUnable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1081)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.main(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:131)
Caused by: com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.CommonConfigurationException: Unable to create InitialContext on address t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299/. Cause: null
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:143)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:128)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:84)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.getConfigurationAccessor(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:41)
        at egi.msdp.nim.ldap.sync.TriggerSynchronizationProcess.getMsdpConfig(TriggerSynchronizationProcess.java:1000)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination]
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:792)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:368)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at com.telcordia.csw.commonutil.configuration.ConfigurationAccessProvider.initiateInitialContext(ConfigurationAccessProvider.java:141)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3s://granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available router to destination
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:470)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:321)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:260)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
        ... 16 more





I am new to SSL configuration, Can anyone please suggest, what mistake I am doing and how can this be fixed.

Looking forward for prompt response.
```

Comment: Try to debug the connection with
openssl  s_client -connect host:port
Possibly will give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use openssl to debug the problem

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

The "Destination unreachable" looks like network/connection problem, which should be clearly shown with the command above.

Check your url, port and firewall, try to:

```
ping granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se
telnet granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se 7299
openssl s_client -connect granitemtlb.int.in.nmc.ericsson.se:7299
```

Remember that ping may be blocked, DNS may not work properly so try to use IP instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your SSL connection using t3s protocol is fine. It is reachable because the exception says:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: **Received** fatal alert: unexpected_message

I am not absolutely sure how it is set up in your case but it looks like the connection you are trying to make is routed somewhere else. The stacktrace proves it:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; No available **router** to destination

This **router** is something weblogic specific. And the problem lies between the host you are connecting with t3s and some other server where weblogic thinks the connection must be routed to.

I doubt it is a network problem. Most likely it is either a problem with web logic configuration or (a more specific variant:) an SSL problem between the two server I mentioned above.

You wrote that everything was working before with JDK 1.6.
Are all servers in the cluster **and** your client application running under JDK 1.8 now? If you have some of them still running under JDK 1.6 this can explain the problem.